# I have issue with uploading image and change image on WooCommerce category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am unable to click on the upload button after clicking on that button nothing happens and I am getting this error

```
media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at Object.wp.media (media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product:444)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1:3)
wp.media @ media-models.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2
(anonymous) @ edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product:444
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1:3
```

Comment: Maybe you have some other .js file interfering with WP admin scripts and thus causing that error which blocks it all for you?

Comment: I have added their new theme and woo commerce plugin file, after that, I got a solution